# python3 - Create folder structure based on tree output

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

Using Python I'm extracting the folder tree of Google Drive account, but I'm stuck on how I can create the folder structure locally using `os.makedirs`

The below function currently outputs the tree correctly (I use indent to inspect this). This is how the Google Drive account has its folder structure.

```
def tree_folder_contents(items_array, folder_id, indent):
    for item in items_array:
        if item['parents']:
            for parent in item['parents']:
                if folder_id == parent:
                    if item['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                        print('     ' * indent + item['name'] + ' (indent: ' + str(indent) + ')')
                        tree_folder_contents(items_array, item['id'], indent+1)
```

The tree output:

```
Folder_1 (indent: 0)
Folder_2 (indent: 0)
     Folder_2_1 (indent: 1)
          Folder_2_1_1 (indent: 2)
          Folder_2_1_2 (indent: 2)
          Folder_2_1_3 (indent: 2)
          Folder_2_1_4 (indent: 2)
Folder_3 (indent: 0)
     Folder_3_1 (indent: 1)
          Folder_3_1_1 (indent: 2)
Folder_4 (indent: 0)
Folder_5 (indent: 0)
```

How can I integrate `os.makedirs` into `tree_folder_contents` in order to create that folder structure locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new parameter `folder_path` and I'm creating the folders using the `dest_path = folder_path + item['name']` line.

This is the full code:

```
def tree_folder_contents(items_array, folder_id, folder_path, indent):
    for item in items_array:
        if item['parents']:
            for parent in item['parents']:
                if folder_id == parent:
                    if item['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                        dest_path = folder_path + item['name'].replace( '/', '_' ) + '/'

                        if not os.path.exists(dest_path):
                            os.makedirs(dest_path)

                        print('     ' * indent + item['name'] + ' (indent: ' + str(indent) + ')')
                        tree_folder_contents(items_array, item['id'], dest_path, indent+1)
```

At the first run of `tree_folder_contents`, `folder_path` is the main directory where all account folders will be created in.